# Follow Curve Force Field Doesn't Work?

Tags: particles, force-fields, bezier-curves

I had a Problem Using the Follow CUrve Force Filed in blender 2.77.

This is the Scene:

[image: Before Playing the Animation]

The Highilighted Object is a Plane, with a particle Setting and the curve has a Follow Curve Force Field Applied.

But when I play the animation:
[image: After Playing the Animation]

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way to fix this?

**Another Situation:**

This is the Curve:
[image: Curve]

The Emitter:
[image: The Emitter]

But, When I play the Animation: 
[image]

Any Way to fix this?

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: maybe your curve is not in the good direction (the arrows along the curve line) : curve menu (in edit mode), then 'segments' and 'switch direction'

Comment: I discovered another problem, I will ad in the main question.

Comment: Is it a plane spiral ? How is configured your 'curve guide' ? how is oriented the plane ? eventually upload your blend file here : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix.

You have to check the Path Animation in Curve's properties.

Comment: Mine is checked and this still doesn't work :(